# Error hiding a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to hide a bootstrap modal when an ajax request has completed successfully. The modal closes but when I try to click on the button (to show the modal again), nothing happens - the button becomes unresponsive. This is what I am doing to hide the modal

```
$('.modal').modal('hide');
$(document.body).removeClass("modal-open");
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

Comment: You only need to call `$('.modal').modal('hide');`.

Comment: @StaticBeagle If you call only that, you will have a backdrop

Comment: `'hide'` should remove the backdrop see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/3694/) . Maybe something on your page is conflicting with the modal

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is the correct way of closing or showing a modal using JavaScript.

Please refer to this documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#modalshow

This will guide you how can you properly show or close a modal.

Bootstrap has inbuilt methods to close or show a modal using JavaScript.

Also please mention your bootstrap version.

Answer (score 0):

you just need use

```
$('.modal').modal('hide');
```

this error fix when bootstrap js in last of js library import no js import after bootstrap js.

import that end of your file